# Why did my book write S2- if hydrogen sulfide isn't ionic?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, analytical-chemistry, stoichiometry

**Problem:**

Balance the following reaction using the [ion-electron method](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Inorganic_Chemistry_(Wikibook)/04%3A_Redox_Stability_and_Redox_Reactions/4.02%3A_Balancing_Redox_Reactions#:%7E:text=systematic%20method.%20The-,ion%2Delectron%20method,-allows%20one%20to):

$$\ce{KMnO4 + H2SO4 + H2S -> MnSO4 + S + K2SO4 +H2O}$$

**My book's solution:**

Oxidation half-reaction:

$$\ce{S^{2-}->S + 2e^{-}}\tag{1}$$

$$...$$

**My question:**

1. Is writing $(1)$ correct? I'm asking this because $\ce{H2S}$ is not an ionic compound. How can my book write $\ce{S^2-}$ then?

Comment: Your book is wrong. And you are right. In acidic solution $\ce{H2S}$ is not dissociated, and not deprotonized. It reacts as $\ce{H2S}$. Anyway the ion $\ce{S^{2-}}$ is nearly inexistant even in rather basic solution. The main ion produced by $\ce{H2S}$ in basic solution is $\ce{HS-}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed better to render (1) as

$\ce{H2S -> S +2H^+ + 2e^-}.$

Since you did not ask, I assume you know the permanganate reduction equation. When you combine this reduction with the correctly written reaction for hydrogen sulfide oxidation in acid  you should get

$\ce{5 H2S + 2 MnO4^- + 6H^+ -> 5 S + 2 Mn^{2+} + 8 H2O,}$

where the net hydrogen ions on the left side are interpreted as coming from the sulfuric acid (which is not oxidized or reduced, so does not appear directly in the half-equations). You should then infer that the balanced ratio of reactants is $\ce{5H2S:2KMnO4:3H2SO4}$.